# Dafny : lemmas without bodies

Tags: dafny

I have been using abstract lemmas and functions (without bodies) in a modeling task. In this example,

```
lemma py(c : int) returns (a: int, b :int)
    ensures a*a + b*b == c*c

lemma main(c : int) returns (a: int, b :int)
    ensures a*a + b*b == c*c
{
    a, b := py(c);
}
```

calling py in main ensures that the post-condition is true irrespective of how py is implemented. I have 2 questions:

1. Is it safe to use abstract lemmas/functions in Dafny? The following modification to the above code is verified by Dafny:

   ```
   lemma py(c : int) returns (a: int, b :int)  
       ensures a*a + b*b == c*c  
       ensures a*a + b*b != c*c
   ```

   while I think that may be Dafny should have thrown an error.
2. Should I say `lemma {:axiom} py(...)`? I haven't observed a difference on including `{:axiom}` or `{:imported}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods and functions without bodies are indeed useful when modeling parts of a system that you're not implementing.

However, one has to be careful when giving such methods and functions postconditions, because those become *trusted*, and are not checked by Dafny. In other words, it is potentially *not safe* to use lemmas or functions without bodies if they have postconditions.

That said, such methods and functions are indispensable for modeling, so the fact that they are potentially unsafe does not mean you shouldn't use them. Instead, you should just be extra careful when writing down the postconditions, because they will not be checked.

If you pass Dafny the `/noCheating:1` flag, it will complain about any methods or functions without bodies that have postconditions, and force you to use the `{:axiom}` attribute. This can be helpful even when not passing `/noCheating:1`, just to mark the fact that the postcondition is trusted. It's up to you whether to pass `/noCheating:1` or whether to use the attribute anyways.

Answer (score 1):

As James mentions, a lemma without a body can be useful when modeling behavior that you're not implementing. If you don't give a body, the verifier does not attempt to verify the correctness of the lemma. Therefore, it is essentially an axiom.

Even without the `/noCheating` flag that James mentions, the Dafny compiler will complain about body-less lemmas (and methods and functions). Note that the compiler does not kick in until after the verifier is satisfied. The `{:axiom}` attribute says you're willing to accept responsibility for the truth of the lemma. For a body-less non-ghost method, you can also use the `{:extern}` attribute, which lets you link with code written in other languages. Again, you assume responsibility for the correctness of that external code, since the Dafny verifier won't check it.

Rustan