# Dafny - Functions without bodies

Tags: dafny

According to this answer I found (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47005291/13083263), we are able to define functions without code. I.e., dafny would simply use the pre and pos conditions for verification.

My question is: how can one do that?

For instance, the following code:

```
function test(n: nat): (m: nat)
   ensures m == n+1
```

Gets me the error

```bash
Function _module._default.test has no body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `function` defined without a body can be only be used for verification.  For example, it could be called from `requires` / `ensures` elements or `ghost` code.

One option is to define a `function` with the `{: extern}` attribute (see [here](http://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef.html#sec-extern)), and then provide a native implementation for it.

Comment: That's what I needed.
I was only using the function for verification, so I added ghost to the function using the body-less function and also {:axiom} to the latest.
Thanks for the help :)